# Using PHP to access Gmail using Service Account

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I am trying to list emails from a standard Gmail account (not a Google Apps account) using OAuth2 and a Service Account (actually, I want to send emails – but that can wait).

I have created the Project, created the service account, downloaded the private key, and enabled the Gmail API (and the Calendar API).  I can successfully access my calendar using code very similar to the code below.  However, I am receiving the following error when attempting to list mail messages.

Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: error_description `"Unauthorized client or scope in request."`

(For info. If I comment out the $credential->sub = … line, I get the following error: `“(500) Backend Error”` and I can see that this is logged in the Usage tab of the Developers API page).

Can anyone confirm that what I am trying to do is possible?  And if so, any ideas where to go next?

Here is my code:

```
class mail
{
private $service;

public function __construct($clientid, $keyfile, $account_name, $app_name)
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName($app_name);
    $this->service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);    

    // Load the key in PKCS 12 format
    $key = file_get_contents($keyfile);
    $client->setClientId($clientid);

    $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $account_name, array('https://mail.google.com/'),$key);
    $credentials->sub = 'myemailaddress...@gmail.com';        

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
}
public function list_mail()
{
    try
    {
        $result = $this->service->users_messages->listUsersMessages("me");
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Gmail API error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />");
    }
    return $result;
}    
}

$mail_obj = new mail(CLIENT_ID, KEY_FILE, SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME, APP_NAME);
$result = $mail_obj->list_mail();
```

Comment: For a service account to work you would have to be able to give it access to send emails from said email account.  Do you really think this is possible?

Comment: You have a point - to get the calendar api working, I had to share my calendar with the email address of the service account.  Any ideas how to give the service account access to my email?

Comment: Was kind of my point.  I cant think of any way to give a service account access to your email.   I am going to think on this a bit.

Comment: Check this link https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account on how to give domain-wide delegation access.

Comment: Thanks - I'd seen this, but it only applies to Google Apps.  How do you do this for a regular Google account?

Comment: It seems to me that if it is possible to give delegation access to a service account in a Google Apps account, it should also be possible to give access to a service account in a non-Google Apps account.

Comment: Assuming that is not possible, would it be possible to write a script that uses a standard user login to the API (i.e. not a service account), run that script interactively once, save the refresh token on disk, and then use that refresh token to access the API in the future in a non-interactive way?

Comment: HI engeeaitch, Have you already solved this problem? If yes, could you please send me of those batch because I've also met the problem also. this is my email : samphors.info@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Samphors - I was unable to solve this problem using a regular gmail account.  However, I have had success using a Google Apps account.