# gmail-api I want to read emails from one email address

Tags: gmail-api

I want to read and store images from emails sent to one email address. This web page will be executed by a cron say two times a day.

In the ../credential/clienttype if offers "web" or "Service" 
I tried the "Service" but this does not offer the "Client-secret"  in the json which is needed in the examples.

Is there a full example to read emails from one email address and then delete them

Comment: what language are you trying to use to call the gmail api? I can find multiple examples by simply googling ie: gmail api c# yeilded me a pretty decent walkthrough from Web Stack of Love

Comment: It's PHP I'd like to use. thanks

Comment: The problem is that I want it to run from a cron. It just needs to run and save the images from the emails in that one account. Is this a web? is it a Service? in testing it should run from the command line.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317085/using-php-to-access-gmail-using-service-account on how to access gmail using service account. Also with service account you have to use domain wide delegation  https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation